# Select 2 в Active Form не работает для нескольких моделей на одной странице

Tags: yii2, kartik

Select 2 в Active Form не работает для нескольких моделей на одной странице. Обычный dropdown работает правильно, а вот select не генерит select, но не span элементы, то бишь select становится скрытым виджетом, а span нет, следовательно ничего не видно.

```
  $similar_pages  = SimilarPage::find()
            ->where(['id_page'=>$this->id])
            ->select(['id','id_similar_page'])
            ->orderBy([
                'index' => SORT_ASC
            ])
            ->all();



   foreach ( $similar_pages as $sim_page) {
                            ?>
                                 <li>
                                <?php
                                $form = ActiveForm::begin();
                                ?>



                                <?php

                                echo $form->field($sim_page, 'id_similar_page')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    'data' =>  $pages,
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Выберите страницу ...'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'allowClear' => true
                                    ],
                                ]);
                                ?>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success' ] ) ?>
                                </div>

                                 <a href="/similar-page/delete?id=3&amp;idParent=4" data-method="post"><div class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</div></a>

                                <?php
                                ActiveForm::end();
                                ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php
                        }
```

Comment: Кстати, с CheckboxX такая же фигня. Не работают эти виджеты на кучу моделей на одной странице

Comment: А что у Вас находится в `$similar_pages` и зачем для каждого его элемента рисовать свой `select2`?